# Query traversal is failing in new sandbox but not the old one

Tags: apex, soql, query

I have a basic query in my code like

```
List<Case> givenCases = [ SELECT ParentId, Parent.Other_Case__c, from Case where ID in :caseIds ];
```

This query works well in one sandbox but not a newer sandbox.  In the failing sandbox, it returns the 'ParentId' as expected but `null` for the `Parent.Other_Case__c`.

I have confirmed that my profile has Read/Write access to `ParentId` and `Other_Case__c` on the `Case` object.  I am able to see the correct result of the query when I query it directly from the Developer Console.

Are there any other settings on the Case object I have to set to make this query work in the new sandbox?  My last resort is to re-write the code and break it into two queries.  It's not difficult but it is very bad timing.

Comment: Are both the sandbox full copy ??And have you checked the records which you are trying to pull does it have a valid id in the field Other_Case__c in the new sandbox??

Comment: The new sandbox (the one that is failing) is a full backup.  The old one is not.  I have confirmed that the Other_Case__c field is populated in the Parent of the Case I am querying.

Comment: It had once happened with me. In my case data loading was not done properly. when I used to load the Case object it would show me IDs in the lookup object and in developer console as sell. I'd suggest go to the record for which ID is coming up in the field Other_case__c field and see if it loads any record or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the Case that is failing is basic test data manually entered by the testing team.  I have confirmed it is set up correctly and the query actually returns data in the Developer Console but not in the code.

Comment: Please update with the API version of your `Apex` code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The classes were already set to API Version 34 on both orgs.

Comment: a) you verified that the apex class is the same in both sandboxes, b) if you go to the failing sandbox and use DC execute anonymous to execute the method in question - does it fail? (note - not DC query editor)

Comment: A) Yes, the code is the same.    B) I just tried out the Execute Anonymous option and it does show the ID of Other_Case__c.  I am doing the tests within Salesforce as an Admin so it is a very confusing issue.